# Git clone only works with ssh://git@.. and not with git@

Tags: ssh, git

Any idea why a GIT repo would work only when using `ssh://git@server.com/repo.git` and not also when using `git@server.com/repo.git`?

It's a server setup by someone else so no idea how it was setup but on BitBucket or GitHub I can just use `git@server.com/repo.git` and it works and clones the repo using SSH protocol. Any idea why for this server iy only works when using `ssh://git@server.com/repo.git` ?

So i need to add the `ssh://` in front.

Comment: Does the server use an alternative SSH port? Like `ssh://git@server.com:2222/`

Comment: No. It's 22. As `ssh://git@server.com/repo.git` works while `git@server.com/repo.git` doesn't. I'm not adding the `:port` in any cases. When I try without `ssh://` I get `fatal: repository 'git@server.com/something/repo.git' does not exist`. With `ssh://git@server.com/something/repo.git` it works.

Comment: A configuration issue of some sort (maybe a firewall? username issue?) - I have a similar problem with a setup at my institution. However access via https works - so the solution is to use the rewrite rules from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589682/ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-connection-timed-out

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using the incorrect syntax.

When you remove the `scheme://` prefix, git no longer interprets your address in URL style anymore, but instead as rcp/scp style. But for rcp/scp style addresses, the path must be separated from user@host using a **colon `:`** (specifying a port is not supported). For example:

```
git clone daniels@server.com:repo.git

git clone git@bitbucket.com:daniels/example.git
```

Without the colon, git will only interpret the address as a local path.

(You can see more details in the [git clone](https://gitirc.eu/git-clone.html#URLS) or [git fetch](https://gitirc.eu/git-fetch.html#URLS) manual page.)

Comment: Hah, mystery solved. You are right. Thank you.

Comment: I was using BitBucket server (former Stash, the one you install on your server, not the cloud version) and just copy & pasted the GIT command from there. For some reason they don't add those missing `:`.